# java/jersey Parsing json response with possibly present list

Tags: java, jackson, jersey

I am connecting towards an api that can return either an object, or a list of errors (I'm going to have to provide fictional examples, sorry, but they should be precise):

Expected json:

```
{
    "type":"someType",
    "list": [
        {
            "attribute":"someAttribute"
        }
    ]
}
```

When error:

```
[
    {
        "error":"1",
        "someField":"someValue"
    }
]
```

Using Jersey, I'm currently doing something like this:

```
client.target(endpoint).request().post(Entity.json(request)).readEntity(ResponseObject.class);
```

ResponseObject.java

```
private List<Failure> messages;
private String type;
private List<ListObject> list;
// set/get
```

Failure.java

```
private String error;
private String someField;
// set/get
```

This seems to work just fine when I get the expected json, however I get the `JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of [..] out of START_ARRAY token` exception when the API returns an error.

When I get the error, I can use `response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Failure>>(){});`, however I don't know if it will fail before I attempt to parse the response.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: you can implement ExceptionMapper to send failure JSON in case of exception

Comment: I'll read a bit about it and give it a go. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: By a quick glance, it doesn't seem like what I need. Basically, I just need a way to encapsulate the list in an object, so I can add that object to my expected object. Since new GenericType<List<Object>> works, I thought I could just create a POJO containing List<Object>, however I get the samme error that it cannot be parsed with START_ARRAY

Comment: so you are getting json from client?

Comment: or you are getting exception while converting service response to json that will be sent back to client

Comment: I'm getting a json - an array consisting of different scenarios (like "phone number is not a valid phone number") on the form that I added an example for under the "Error" part of my question.

Basically, I only need to know how to properly encapsulate a list in a pojo, and I think I can solve it from there (since class A { List<Object> list }  doesn't work)

Comment: Are you getting `HTTP 200` for both the cases? If not, then you can use HTTP status for doing the error case identification.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting HTTP 200 for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my problem would go away if I could do something like:

```
try {
    return response.readEntity(ResponseObject.class);
} catch (MappingException ex) {
    ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
    responseObject.setFailureList(response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Failure>>(){});
    return responseObject;
}
```

however, readEntity closes the stream, so this is not possible.

I ended up doing a workaround where I read to String from the response first (to get the raw result and closing the stream), then attempt to parse it, and if I get an initial parsing error, I try to parse it as an error message:

```
private <T> T parseAfterPayJson(String json, Class<T> responseClass) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
        return gson.fromJson(json, responseClass);
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException jsex) {
        ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
        responseObject.setFailures(Lists.newArrayList(gson.fromJson(json, Failure[].class)));
        return (T) responseObject; // this part is because of inheritance
    }
}
```